# Json.Net specify custom converter of a property of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, json.net, attributes

To specify which converter Json.Net serializer should use when dealing with a property, we usually use `JsonConverterAttribute`, which is a nice and neat syntax.
However, because C# doesn't support the use of generic type parameters in Attribute, trouble occurs when the declaring class of property contains generic type parameters. Here's a simple example:

```
public class FooConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        //Implementation
    }

    public override T ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        //Implementation
    }
}

public class Bar<T>{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter<T>))] //CS0416 'T': an attribute argument cannot use type parameters
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can instantiate a generic converter and pass it with JsonSerializerSettings when calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, but that requires the caller to know such implementation detail of the type being deserialized. What I'm writing is a library, I don't want to bother my user to manually add a converter each time he needs to deserialize a object of such type.
**Is there any workaround when my custom converter *do* rely on the type parameter?**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a non-generic converter, e.g.

```cs
public class FooConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; } // or false if you don't need custom read
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can use `[FooConverter]` as an attribute.  It won't be type-safe but there's no other way to do this because of the unbound nature of generics.  However, as long as you return an object of type `objectType` in the `ReadJson` method, you won't have any problems.

More information is [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is: if I had known what `T` is at startup, why would I bother to use a type parameter?

Comment: Of course.. I need my morning coffee! I'll update my answer, you'll need to do it a different way I think.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I've been struggling with this problem for a long time, ending up with no satisfying solution. So I have no way but come here for help :(

Comment: I've updated the answer to be non-generic - do you think that might work?